# How do I pull the XML attributes via a PHP import reading a CSV?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, csv

Currently I am looking to take a xml feed, download it as a csv and then pull the data I need and place it into a MySQL database.  Currently I pull the feed down to the directory with no problem.  I do this using the following code.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($csv_path);
$root_name = $xml->getName();
$xml_array = xml2array($xml_url);
//print_r ($xml_array);exit;
$events = array();
$keys = array_keys($xml_array[$root_name]['sport-event']);
if ($keys[0] == '0') {
$events = $xml_array[$root_name]['sport-event'];
} else {
    $events[] = $xml_array[$root_name]['sport-event'];
}
```

I've pulled information before and I have been able to pull the information when the data is in tags such as   using a $e['game']['hometeam'].  However I'm trying to pull data that is within the attributes(possibly wrong term).  Example of what the feed looks like.

```
<sport-event>
<event-metadata league="Soccer" event-type="0" league-details="UEFA Champs" event-date-time="11/24/2015 02:45 PM" eventNum="2962160" status="" off-the-board="False"/>
<team>
<team-metadata alignment="Home" nss="13498" openNum="13498">
<name full="Roma"/>
</team-metadata>
<wagering-stats>
<wagering-moneyline bookmaker-name="Pinnacle" active="true" line="733" context="current"/>
</wagering-stats>
<team-stats score="0"/>
</team>
```

How do I pull the information such as league, league-details etc so that I can pull this into a SQL query to insert into my database.  Thanks in advanced

Comment: if you `var_dump` the $xml, can you see the attributes? I don't see attributes being accessed in the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Comment: Got it, when I went and used the var_dump I found that I needed to use $e['event-metadata_attrib]['league'] I got the information I needed! so simple but I was completely unaware of how to use var_dump.  This is going to save me TONS of times with things down the line.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Got it, when I went and used the var_dump I found that I needed to use $e['event-metadata_attrib]['league'] I got the information I needed! so simple but I was completely unaware of how to use var_dump. This is going to save me TONS of times with things down the line. THANK YOU!